# GCP: Unable to try Cloud Billing Account API from Java

Tags: java, api, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Hello I cannot use the API method billingAccounts.get of GCP.

Steps made: copy/paste of the Java code from the Google documentation (https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/billingAccounts/get).

I am using a service account as credential(env key value in eclipse "..CREDENTIALS=JSON file path"), I added to it an admin role. (I cannot add the permission to use billingAccounts.get from the role Billing Administrator)

Some ideas?

Comment: Need more details. What errors are you getting? What admin role did you give the account? Was that on the org level or project level?

Comment: Thanks for answering. 403 access denied; role=project editor; project level.

Comment: As I can see at https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/billingAccounts/get "authenticated user **must be a viewer of the billing account**."  to run `Method: billingAccounts.get` and at https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#overview-of-cloud-billing-roles-in-cloud-iam required role "Billing Account Viewer (`roles/billing.viewer`)"  is at the level "Organization or billing account".

Comment: Can you add role "Billing Account Viewer (`roles/billing.viewer`)" to your service account and try again?

Comment: In addition, have a look at the Cloud IAM Policy Hierarchy at  https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#policy_hierarchy

Comment: I cannot add that role. If I select the permission billingAccounts.get it outputs "NOT APPLICABLE for project level custom roles". Maybe I need to change my account permissions?

Comment: Have a look at this step by step guide https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#update-cloud-billing-permissions. Can you edit Cloud Billing permissions?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza The last guide you provided resolved my problem. The service account was not included in the billing viewer permissions. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! Please mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have enough permissions to use this API.

Have a look at the description of  [Method: billingAccounts.get](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/billingAccounts/get):

> The current authenticated user must be a [viewer of the billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access).

and at the [Overview of Cloud Billing roles in Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#overview-of-cloud-billing-roles-in-cloud-iam) you can find:

[image: billing_roles]

**To obtain necessary permissions** you should follow this step by step guide [Update Cloud Billing permissions](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#update-cloud-billing-permissions).